# Condition, two lines from multiple lines contains element

Tags: vb.net

Condition, I should put a condition, there should be at least 2 lines with value 0 to be entered in the box.

Here: There must be at least 2 lines containing ("0000000000") to be entered in the box. how do i do this

```
 If line.Contains("0000000000") Then
 LBMsgALstofScan.Text = ("0")
```

He now enters the box, if there is a single line of all that is the value.

> Expected Output: If line1.contains and line2.contains = ("0000000000") Then

```
LBMsgALstofScan.Text = ("0")
```

Code:

```
 Private Sub PrivateRemizeScan1()
        TxtListScanTxt.Lines = TxtListScanTxt.Lines.Where(
    Function(line) Not line.Contains("{ LstScan = , DrwR2 = 0000000000 }")).ToArray()
        For Each line As String In TxtListScanTxt.Lines
            If line.Contains("0000000000") Then
                LBMsgALstofScan.Text = ("0")
            ElseIf line.Contains("0000000001") Then
                LBMsgALstofScan.Text = ("1")
            ElseIf line.Contains("0000000002") Then
                LBMsgALstofScan.Text = ("2")
        Next
        End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that you want to check whether a `TextBox` has at least two lines that contain the text "0000000000" then you can do this:

```vb
If myTextBox.Lines.Count(Function(line) line.Contains("0000000000")) >= 2 Then
```